# How to post raw body data with curl?

Tags: linux, curl, post, request, http-post

Before you post this as a duplicate; I've tried many of the suggestions I found around SO.

So far I've been using postman to post data to a Java web service. That works great as follows:

[image]

I now want to do the same using curl, so I tried it using the following ways:

```bash
$ curl -X POST --data "this is raw data" http://78.41.xx.xx:7778/
$ curl -X POST --data-binary "this is raw data" http://78.41.xx.xx:7778/
$ curl -X POST --data "@/home/kramer65/afile.txt" http://78.41.xx.xx:7778/
$ curl -X POST --data-binary "@/home/kramer65/afile.txt" http://78.41.xx.xx:7778/
```

Unfortunately, all of those show an empty raw body on the receiving side.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? How is my curl request different from my postman request? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 150, accepted):

curl's `--data` will by default send `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in the request header. However, when using Postman's `raw` body mode, Postman sends `Content-Type: text/plain` in the request header.

So to achieve the same thing as Postman, specify `-H "Content-Type: text/plain"` for curl:

```bash
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/plain" --data "this is raw data" http://78.41.xx.xx:7778/
```

Note that if you want to watch the full request sent by Postman, you can enable debugging for packed app. Check [this link](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/errors) for all instructions. Then you can inspect the app (right-click in Postman) and view all requests sent from Postman in the `network` tab :

[image]

Comment: It should be noted though that the body part is sent *exactly* the same. This just changes a header.

Comment: I found myself here merely looking for a shorter _curl_ command line. I'm quite pleased that _curl_ is savvy enough that I can omit the '-X POST' part, but somewhat chagrined that needing to add that rather lengthy header puts me back in the woods. Shorter is better -- when it's possible.