# Bad request: missing request body while using curl

Tags: http, curl

I am getting the below error when trying to query PUT command with curl :
`"error":"bad_request","reason":"Missing request body"`

this is the query i am trying to execute to insert a new document in the database:

```
curl -X PUT  http://127.0.0.1:5984/mychannel_fabcar/CAR10/  '{"docs" : [ "_id": "CAR10", "colour": "white","make": "Ford", "model": "Figo","owner": "Meghna","~version": "\u0000CgMBAgA="]}'
```

Comment: The error tells you the exact problem.

Comment: Also, there's no such thing as a "fauxton database". Fauxton is just a web UI for CouchDB. And by using curl, you're not using fauxton at all. So fauxton is 100% unrelated to what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

shouldn't you also give the option `-d` for the body?

```
curl -X PUT   http://127.0.0.1:5984/mychannel_fabcar/CAR10/  -d '{"docs": [ "_id": "CAR10", "colour": "white","make": "Ford", "model":"Figo","owner": "Meghna","~version": "\u0000CgMBAgA="]}'
```

see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912924/how-to-send-file-contents-as-body-entity-using-curl) (uploading files) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43054195/how-to-post-raw-body-data-with-curl/43056956) (uploading raw data) for a detailed explanantion.